# Getting router parameters in Store using Alt and React-Router

Tags: reactjs, flux, react-router

I'm building a simple app using react-router and Alt, and I'm on a page with router parameters. I've built a store for this page, and I want to get the current router parameters in the store.

Here's my Store code:

```
var alt = require('../alt.jsx'),
    Router = require('react-router'),
    State = Router.State,

    videoActions = require('../actions/videoActions.jsx')

    class videoStore {
        constructor() {
            console.log(State.getParams())
        }
    }

module.exports = alt.createStore(videoStore)
```

However, I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'router' of undefined
```

I know I could do this from the component itself using the State mixin, but I'm trying to initialize the state in the Store itself.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Why couple the store with the router? Can't you pass the router params as parameters to an action?

Comment: @limelights Oh god I feel so stupid now. Post your suggestion as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks so much :)

Comment: Even if you pass them as params, you will not have access to the routes, this is intended for components who know about "state", not for use outside of components. I posted a working solution that would work outside of components, please look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is due to the nature of how ReactJS works and that the "state" is not visible outside of components. We ran into this not too long ago and after researching the matter, we did the following:

- Created a router.js file which copied some methods over from router.
- Created a routes.js which contained the actual routes for our project.

router.js

```
var router;

module.exports = {  
    makePath: function(to, params, query) {
    return router.makePath(to, params, query);
    },

    makeHref: function(to, params, query) {
    return router.makeHref(to, params, query);
    },

    transitionTo: function(to, params, query) {
    router.transitionTo(to, params, query);
    },

    replaceWith: function(to, params, query) {
    router.replaceWith(to, params, query);
    },

    goBack: function() {
    router.goBack();
    },

    run: function(render) {
    router.run(render);
    }
};

var routes = require('./routes');
var Router = require('react-router');

router = Router.create({
    routes: routes, 
    location: Router.HistoryLocation
});
```

routes.js

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;
var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
...
var routes = (
    <Route name="app" path="/admin" handler={APP}>

        <Route name="login" path="/admin/login/" handler={Login} />

        <Route name="home" path="/admin/home" handler={Home} />

    </Route>
);
module.exports = routes;
```

In your components you would access the react-router as you would normally, but in the actions/stores, you would require the router.js file that you created instead so that it would work outside the components. There are many similar examples on the web that you will find, this definitely works and is something that we are using. Let us know how this works out for you.

Comment: Thanks for that. While it did work, I think limelight's answer is more elegant, and follows the principles of Flux more closely.

Thanks for the taking the time to write this :)

Comment: Glad you found the solution! If you don't mind updating your question with the solution for future viewers (myself included), so that we can benefit from it as well, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution. Thanks to limelight for paving the way. Flux was designed to have a one-way data flow, and what I wanted to do violated this by having two flows.

I ended up creating an action called setParams (with a payload of the router params) , and dispatching that action in componentWillMount. Then I stored these in the component's state (in a variable called routerParams). Then I could access it anytime. (this.state.routerParams.videoId)

I understand that state should be used as little as possible, but this seemed like something that SHOULD be in a component's state.

If anyone else has a better solution, do let me know :)